# Does $\partial_b u(\cdot,b) \in L^2(A)$ for fixed $b$ imply that $u(\cdot,b) \in L^2(A)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $u$ be defined on $A \times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are two bounded domains, and write $u=u(a,b)$.

Suppose that the weak derivative $\partial_b u(\cdot,b) \in L^2(A)$ for fixed $b$. Does this imply that $u(\cdot,b) \in L^2(A)$?

Comment: Maybe you can use [differentiation under the integral sign](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Here is a *hint* on how to construct a counterexample,  put
$$g(x,y)= \sin(y\,h(x)),$$

then $g'_y(x,y)=h(x)\cos(y\,h(x))$.